# How to set two way binding for a date object?

Tags: datepicker, angular6

I'm trying to implement DatePicker to return a Date Value similar to this example in Angular 6

https://stackblitz.com/angular/klxqgnondlx?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

It works great . . . . . . .  but it returns a `JSON` date rather than `Date` object, so the two way binding with a corresponding date field doesn't work.

**I need the date picker to return `Date` object not `JSON`**

Here is what I tried

```
   <input class="form-control" type="date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd"
     id ="myDate" name="myDate" [(ngModel)]="model.myDate| date:'yyyy-mm-dd'" ngbDatepicker #d="ngbDatepicker"  (ngModelChange)="myDate= $event" >
```

But it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is returned is up to the library you are using. You could always use a different library. It might be easiest to just make your model a string (representation as JSON date), and convert it to a Date object when you actually need to use the Date representation.